# What timestamp is being used by Amazon Connect for recordings filename? Initiation timestamp or Disconnect timestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-connect, call-recording

As we know amazon connect record the calls and store the recordings on S3 bucket, I am looking for what timestamp I can use to make the filename by myself in my code!

There are two timestamps e.g. Initiation timestamp & Disconnect timestamp are being used while creating filenames with `contactId_timestamp_UTC` e.g. `7bb75057-76ae-4e7e-a140-44a50cc5954b_20220418T06:44_UTC.wav.`

I have used the callStartTime to create these filenames and then get the files from S3 using SignedURL but in few cases there is a difference of 1 sec as file stored with incremental of one sec on S3 and I couldn't get the file form S3.

For example I the filename is been created by my application is: `7bb75057-76ae-4e7e-a140-44a50cc5954b_20220418T06:44_UTC.wav.` but the recording stored on S3 has filename as: `7bb75057-76ae-4e7e-a140-44a50cc5954b_20220418T06:45_UTC.wav.`

The last thing can this data (timestamp) is available in contact object? so I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the timestamp for the file name is based on ConnectedToAgentTimestamp which makes sense as the recording doesn't start until the caller is talking to an agent. ConnectedToAgentTimestamp is under AgentInfo in the contact details...

```
{
    "Contact": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:connect:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/contact/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "InitiationMethod": "INBOUND",
        "Channel": "VOICE",
        "QueueInfo": {
            "Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "EnqueueTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:05:45.334000+12:00"
        },
        "AgentInfo": {
            "Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "ConnectedToAgentTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:06:25.706000+12:00"
        },
        "InitiationTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:05:15.869000+12:00",
        "DisconnectTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:08:08.298000+12:00",
        "LastUpdateTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:08:08.299000+12:00"
    }
}
```